# Find paired records after groupby Python

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe like this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(
    [['101', 'a', 'in', '10'],
     ['101', 'a', 'out', '10'], 
     ['102', 'b', 'in', '20'], 
     ['103', 'c', 'in', '30'],
     ['103', 'c', 'out', '40']], 
    columns=['col1', 'col2', 'col3', 'col4']
)
```

I want to group by col1 and find paired records that have the same value in col2 and col4, but one has 'in' in col3 one has 'out' in col3. The expected outcome is:

```
df_out = pd.DataFrame(
    [['101', 'a', 'in', '10'],
     ['101', 'a', 'out', '10']],
    columns=['col1', 'col2', 'col3', 'col4']
)
```

Thank you for the help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let us try `transform` with `nunique`

```
out = df[df.groupby(['col1','col2','col4'])['col3'].transform('nunique')==2]
Out[187]: 
  col1 col2 col3 col4
0  101    a   in   10
1  101    a  out   10
```

Comment: Thank you for the help! Just want to add a follow-up question regarding to this, what if I have another datetime column, say col5, and I want to specifically find records that 'in' took place earlier than 'out'? Is there a way to modify the code to filter the results? Thanks!

Comment: @J_jane sort_values with col5, then do df[df.groupby(['col1','col2','col4'])['col3'].transform('sum')=='inout']